# Push Notification not coming when app got cleared from background in Xiaomi devices

Tags: push-notification

I have a created a chat application which sends push notifications to users. In Xiaomi devices(Mine is Mi4i) I am receiving push notification only if my app is in background. If i cleared the app from background or recent list push notification doesn't come.

I have tried turning on **Auto start** functionality as mentioned by few posts but still no notifications received.

**Note :** Every other brand devices are receiving notifications with the same scenario nicely.

I wonder how do i do this, Does anyone has snippets which helps me?

Comment: I have the same issue, but wonder why Facebook or Whatsapp can works :(

Comment: After searching a long, i found that Xiaomi devices has default Battery setting which blocks all background activities including Push Notifications. To enable go to Settings->Battery Settings->Manage apps battery usage-> Choose apps->Your app->Select No restrictions.

For Facebook and WhatsApp few links shows that Xiaomi has whitelisted these apps as being popular apps, LOL but seems to true.

Comment: Note : Same goes for ASUS phones as well. Open Auto-Start and click Allow to get notifications.